# How to retrieve and use a tar.gz.asc from github in an Ansible playbook? With a given gpg key?

Tags: github, ansible

I am trying to install *ruby-install* per the instructions under "PGP" [here](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install#readme) but via an Ansible playbook.

The playbook is now erroring out syntactically with the "gpg:" line below.

I've Googled quite a bit but still haven't found examples that made the concept click for me.  Couldn't find Ansible documentation on gpg.

This is related to building a Vagrant dev vm easily reproducible and easily change-controlled, so I'd rather not add complexity by just installing from the command line or via another script after the VM is up.

```
- name: get gpg for ruby install via the postmodern developer
  get_url:    
    url: https://raw.github.com/postmodern/postmodern.github.io/master/postmodern.asc
    dest: /tmp/postmodern.asc

- name: import gpg key    
  gpg:
    key_file: /tmp/postmodern.asc

# To do later:     

# wget https://raw.github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/master/pkg/ruby-#install-0.7.0.tar.gz.asc
# gpg --verify ruby-install-0.7.0.tar.gz.asc ruby-install-0.7.0.tar.gz
```

I expected the *gpg* command to add the gpg key in the file to the system's collection, but the results were as follows:

```
[WARNING]: Ansible is in a world writable directory (/vagrant), ignoring it as an ansible.cfg source.
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
ERROR! no action detected in task

The error appears to have been in     '/vagrant/ansible/roles/framework/tasks/main.yml': line 15, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- name: import gpg key
  ^ here
Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

Comment: I don't see a `gpg` module in Ansible. That's what the error message `ERROR! no action detected in task` usually means, that the task is either missing a module declaration or the module asked for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [gpg module](https://github.com/brandonkal/ansible-gpg), but it's not included in the stock Ansible install. If you want to use it, you can [install it](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#adding-a-module-locally).

Personally, I'd just shell out for this like so:

```
- name: import gpg key    
  command: gpg --verify ruby-install-0.7.0.tar.gz.asc ruby-install-0.7.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: Actually, I needed a greater understanding of which files were which -- the package I wanted to install vs two different signature files.  The package turned out not to be encrypted.